# How to create app bar with icons using TabLayout Android Design?

Tags: android-tabhost, android-tabs, android-design-library

I'm trying to use the new TabLayout in the android design library to create app bar with icons.

```
public void setupTabLayout(TabLayout tabLayout) {
    tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_CENTER);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewpager);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tabbar_library);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tabbar_recents);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tabbar_favorites);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tabbar_notifications);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(4).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tabbar_settings);
}
```

Result:

[image: app bar with icons]

Please help me to create app bar similar:

[image: app bar with icons]

Sorry my english is not good.Thanks is advance !

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From the documentation :

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.Tab.html#setCustomView(android.view.View)

> Set a custom view to be used for this tab. This overrides values set
>   by setText(CharSequence) and setIcon(Drawable).

**you will have to set the title values yourself**

From your example:

```
public void setupTabLayout(TabLayout tabLayout) {
    tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_CENTER);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewpager);

    TextView tab = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
    tab.setText("Library");
    tab.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.ic_tabbar_library, 0, 0);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tab);
    //..
}
```

custom_tab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tab" />
```

**Update**

The api has changed to allow you to set a custom id so you don't have to set the text/drawable manually. It'll use the adapter's values.

> If the provided view contains a TextView with an ID of text1 then that
>   will be updated with the value given to setText(CharSequence).
>   Similarly, if this layout contains an ImageView with ID icon then it
>   will be updated with the value given to setIcon(Drawable).

Comment: thanks for your support @Chris Dinon. This is my solution: https://github.com/natuan0rg/Android-Design-Support-Library-Sample/tree/master/AndroidDesignTabLayout

Comment: thanks a lot it works, but i must inflate custom_tab every time i need to add it i can't use the same one, do you know why?

Comment: how do you show the text? I can only see the icon :(

Comment: @YousefZakher if your view isn't too complex you could just instantiate it at runtime like say: TextView tabText = new TextView(MainActivity.this);

Comment: @Chris Dinon: If there is another fragment inside tablayout fragment, on opening second fragment, the tab items are recreated and the modification is removed.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the attribute `android:layout` of `TabItem` to set custom view.
In custom view xml file, remember to set `id` of icon and text view to `@android:id/icon` and `android:id="@android:id/text1"`, then the library will take care the rest.

Here's an example:

. custom_tab_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

  <ImageView
      android:id="@android:id/icon"
      android:layout_width="16dp"
      android:layout_height="16dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
      android:scaleType="centerInside"/>

  <TextView
      android:id="@android:id/text1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
      android:textSize="16dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

. main.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
      android:id="@+id/ti_activities"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_question"
      android:layout="@layout/custom_tab_item"
      android:text="@string/activities"/>

  <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
      android:id="@+id/ti_profile"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_question"
      android:layout="@layout/custom_tab_item"
      android:text="@string/Profile"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 2):

As [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) said You can add items to `TabLayout` through the xml by use of `TabItem`. An example usage is like:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="match_parent">

     <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
             android:text="@string/tab_text"/>

     <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
             android:icon="@drawable/ic_android"/>

 </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

Comment: layout height and width should be defined.

Comment: @jani If not AS gives you warning

Comment: added just so that a newbie does not freak out :P

Answer (score 1):

When you use [vector drawables as icons](https://material.io/icons/) you might want to reuse a single drawables for different states, by simply tinting it differently. [This way you can reduce the apk size and the allocation of resources.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u5xP4tFQlkA&index=4&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc-9gqRx5anfX0Ozp-qEI2CF) First define a custom FragmentPagerAdapter (I am using kotlin instead of java here)

```
class TabPagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fm) {

    override fun getCount(): Int = 2

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment = when (position) {
        0 -> FirstFragment.newInstance()
        else -> SecondFragment.newInstance()
    }

    fun getPageIcon(context: Context, position: Int): Drawable = when (position) {
        0 -> ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_whatshot)
        else -> ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_face)
    }
}
```

Instead of implementing `getPageTitle` we create a `getPageIcon` method, that returns a drawable for a specific tab. Next we create a custom TabLayout:

```
class IconTabLayout : TabLayout {

    private var viewPager: ViewPager? = null

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet) : super(context, attributeSet)
    constructor(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attributeSet, defStyleAttr)

    override fun onAttachedToWindow() {
        if (viewPager == null) {
            if (parent is ViewPager) viewPager = parent as ViewPager
        }
        super.onAttachedToWindow()
    }

    override fun setupWithViewPager(viewPager: ViewPager?, autoRefresh: Boolean) {
        this.viewPager = viewPager
        super.setupWithViewPager(viewPager, autoRefresh)
    }

    override fun addTab(@NonNull tab: Tab, position: Int, setSelected: Boolean) {
        if (viewPager != null && viewPager!!.adapter is TabPagerAdapter) {
            val icon: Drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap((viewPager!!.adapter as TabPagerAdapter).getPageIcon(context, position))
            DrawableCompat.setTintList(icon.mutate(), ContextCompat.getColorStateList(context, R.color.tab_color))
            tab.icon = icon
        }
        super.addTab(tab, position, setSelected)
    }
}
```

So the magic happens in the `addTab` method, where the icon and the color state list are set. The color state list has following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Non focused states -->
    <item android:color="@color/tab_not_active" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false" />
    <item android:color="@color/tab_active" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true" />

    <!-- Focused states -->
    <item android:color="@color/tab_not_active" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false" />
    <item android:color="@color/tab_active" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true" />

    <!-- Pressed -->
    <item android:color="@color/tab_not_active" android:state_pressed="true" />
</selector>
```