# Modifying ViewPager Tabs according to the theme of the application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I have created a simple ViewPager tabview. The tabview has a custom theme which I have designed.

**The tabview looks like this:**

[image: Tabview screenshot]

**The layout XML file for the tabview**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

**The custom theme I have created for the ViewPager:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<resources>

    <style name="Theme.Custom_tab_theme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_custom_tab_theme</item>
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Custom_tab_theme</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Custom_tab_theme</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Custom_tab_theme</item>
        <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Custom_tab_theme</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Custom_tab_theme</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_custom_tab_theme</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_custom_tab_theme</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Custom_tab_theme</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>

    </style>


    <style name="TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.Solid.Custom_tab_theme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_solid_custom_tab_theme</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_custom_tab_theme</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_custom_tab_theme</item>
        <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Custom_tab_theme</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.Transparent.Custom_tab_theme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_transparent_custom_tab_theme</item>
        <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Custom_tab_theme</item>
    </style>

    <style name="PopupMenu.Custom_tab_theme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_custom_tab_theme</item>  
    </style>

    <style name="DropDownListView.Custom_tab_theme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ListView.DropDown">
        <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_custom_tab_theme</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Custom_tab_theme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_custom_tab_theme</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DropDownNav.Custom_tab_theme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_custom_tab_theme</item>
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_custom_tab_theme</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_custom_tab_theme</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ProgressBar.Custom_tab_theme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_horizontal_custom_tab_theme</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionButton.CloseMode.Custom_tab_theme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.CloseMode">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_cab_done_custom_tab_theme</item>
    </style>

    <!-- this style is only referenced in a Light.DarkActionBar based theme -->
    <style name="Theme.Custom_tab_theme.Widget" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Custom_tab_theme</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Custom_tab_theme</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Now I want to customise the TabView more to include the icons and change the icons and text color of the ViewPager when selected.

**Something which I want to achieve:**

[image: Output wanted]

So, basically I want to do 3 things:

1. Add picture to the tabs
2. Change picture and text color of tabs when selected
3. Change font style of Tab text (remove bold and use custom font)

What should I do to implement the same? Should the Custom theme be modified?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create app bar with icons using TabLayout Android Design?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30614272/how-to-create-app-bar-with-icons-using-tablayout-android-design)

Comment: you can make your own custom view for getting user defined view.

Comment: @AbhishekPatel any guide to support your comment will be very helpful.

Comment: @kittu88 this is the best example for custom tab this may be help to u..http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using [`TabLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) from the Design Library (if you aren't, you probably should, as it's rather easy to use). The class documentation explains how to set it up with a ViewPager, but that will only give the tabs a title and not an icon. You can simply add the icons yourself afterward:

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(...);
// normal setup, text-only tabs
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
// add the icons
for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
    TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);
    tab.setIcon(R.drawable.tab_icon); // different icon per tab
}
```

To colorize the icons, you can use [state list drawables](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) to show a different colored icon for `android:state_selected="true"`. You can do the same thing for the text by making a [color state list](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html) and the same state attribute.

To make the text not bold, you can apply your own text appearance to the TabLayout. Do this by making a style declaration (notice I also apply the aforementioned color state list here):

```
<!-- TextAppearance.Design.Tab is the default used in the Design Library -->
<style name="TabTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/tab_text_color_state_list</color>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif</color>
</style>
```

Then use it in your layout:

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    ... >

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabTextAppearance" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this from your PagerAdapter.

```
private int[] imageResId = {
        R.drawable.ic_one,
        R.drawable.ic_two,
        R.drawable.ic_three
};

// ...

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    // Generate title based on item position
    // return tabTitles[position];

    // getDrawable(int i) is deprecated, use getDrawable(int i, Theme theme) for min SDK >=21
    // or ContextCompat.getDrawable(Context context, int id) if you want support for older versions.
    // Drawable image = context.getResources().getDrawable(iconIds[position], context.getTheme());
    // Drawable image = context.getResources().getDrawable(imageResId[position]);

    Drawable image = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, imageResId[position]);
    image.setBounds(0, 0, image.getIntrinsicWidth(), image.getIntrinsicHeight());
    SpannableString sb = new SpannableString(" ");
    ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(image, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
    sb.setSpan(imageSpan, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    return sb;
}
```

Comment: How to change the tab icons and tab text colors dynamically? How to change the font style?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1) Add picture to the tabs

```
    // here you add an array of your icon   
 final int[] ICONS = new int[] {
                    R.drawable.ic_browse,
                    R.drawable.ic_start,
                    R.drawable.ic_collage,
            };

for (int i=0; i < tabs.length; i++)
        {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tabs[i])
                                 .setIcon(NewsFeedActivity.this.getResources().getDrawable(ICONS[i]))
                                 .setTabListener(this));
        }//endfor
```

and

2) Change picture and text color of tabs when selected

you can use `tabHost.getCurrentTab()` onResume() of both the activity to detect which tab you have selected.